# Force ViewPager to recalculate page widths

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager

When I first load the ViewPager, I made it display 3 pages by default by overriding the getPageWidth() method. Though after performing an action on the application, I resize the ViewPager to 1/3 of the screen size, and instead of getPageWidth() returning 1/3, it returns 1. This is so that the ViewPager only displays 1 page at a time.

My problem that I am having is that the pages do not resize the pages after I resize the ViewPager. The ViewPager still displays 3 pages unless I swipe several times to the left/right.

Is there a way that I can force the ViewPager to recalculate and redraw all pages?

Comment: Have you tried `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: That brought some progress. Now only one page is visible as intended, but it is only 1/3 the width of the ViewPager.

Comment: Do you have this method implemented in your viewpager adapter:   @Override
  public int getItemPosition(Object object){
   return POSITION_NONE;
  }

Comment: I do have that function overridden.